# Limit elements from a list in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python list of 300+ elements. I am trying to limit the print of the elements from the list, in order to show only 10 at a time.

Here is an example with only 5 elements inside a list, and I want to show just 2:

```
items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

max_num = 2

for item in items:
 # here I am not sure how I restrict the number elements from items

 # do something
```

Comment: Slice your list like this: `for item in items[:max_num]:`

Comment: is :limit a number so it would be items[2]?

Comment: What do you mean by "at a time"? Do you want it to dump the whole thing at once but with ten items per row? Or do you want the user to press Enter to show the next ten? Or something else?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

### 1. (Pythonic way)

As @aa333 suggested:

```
for item in items[:max_num]:
   print(item)
```

### 2. Probably a bit faster:

```
for i in xrange(max_num):
   print(items[i])
```

### 3. Using a while loop:

```
counter = 0
while counter < max_num:
   print(items[i])
   counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
a = range(300)
for i in range(len(a)):
    limit = 10;
    i=(i*limit)
    print a[i:(i+limit)]
    if(i>(len(a)-limit-1)):
        break;
```

This is the basic answer. I am sure better logic is available than this.

```
Output is like:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]......
```

Hope this is the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the question, it could be done in the following way:

```
from math import floor
from numpy import arange
max_num=10.
lis=arange(0,404)
len_num=int(floor(float(len(lis))/max_num))
for i in range(len_num):
  print lis[i*int(max_num):(i+1)*int(max_num)]
  wait=input()
print(lis[(i+1)*int(max_num):])
```

This way, your list is shown slice by slice and the next slice isn't shown until the user presses one key

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
>>> m = 300
>>> k=range(m)
>>> s = 0
>>> e = 10
>>> while m > 0:
...  print k[s:e]
...  s+=10
...  e+=10
...  m-=10
...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
[70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]
[120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129]
[130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139]
[140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149]
[150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159]
[160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169]
[170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179]
[180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189]
[190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199]
[200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209]
[210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219]
[220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229]
[230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239]
[240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249]
[250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259]
[260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269]
[270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279]
[280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289]
[290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299]
```